# How to make an official Javascript Library ? Does it need any certification or permissions to make it?

Tags: javascript

I had learned a little of javascript and wants to make a JS library, I wants to know that -"does it takes any official permissions to make a JS library and also how to be owner of those codes, how to relese it officially",
does it takes long time to setup such project??
What it needed more then JS codes?

Answer (score 0):

Getting started with npm is easy. All you need is an account.
https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry